# Why is the speed of a rolling ball related to the incline?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration

Considering that the gravitational acceleration is constant and the air resistance is insignificant at low speeds, why is it that a ball rolls faster down a steeper incline?

Comment: If you increase the steepness, you will increase the acceleration of the ball which rolls down the ramp.

Comment: Because the gravitational force is **not** constant. It is constant in terms of magnitude, not in terms of direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extreme example showing that it does matter, consider the case when the steep is 0. Obviously the ball will not accelerate. This is because the normal force from the ground will oppose the ball's weight completely.

The other extreme, in which the steep has a 90-degree inclination, it's just a free fall. There is no normal force.

Anything in between, there will be a normal force keeping the ball from falling into the ground. This normal force will somewhat oppose the weight, in a way that depends on the sine of the angle of inclination.

Comment: Correct... but I think this is one of those questions/answers were a picture is worth a thousand words.